# C# - Access variable Names dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, automation

I am automating a web page. i have captured and saved the Links in a file.

```
Link Url_0="gmail.com"
Link Url_1="ymail.com"
Link Url_2="hotmail.com"
Link Url_3="outlook.com"
```

The below statement will click on each url.

```
HomePage.Url_0.Click();//Homepage is the Class name
```

I want to Click these URLs one by one. So I am using a for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
String url=String.Format("Url_{0}",i);
HomePage.url.Click(); //This is throwing me error (I think that this is not correct way to do.)
Sleep(2000);
}
```

How can I proceed here ? Can this be done in any way ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You **seriously** need to read about arrays!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the variables into a collection, rather than having a different variable with a different name for each.  It's technically possible to access the variable in the manor you describe, but it's not what a language like C# is designed to do, and would be *very* bad practice.

There are several collections to choose from.  Here a `List` is probably appropriate, an array could work as well.

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>()
{
    "gmail.com",
    "ymail.com",
    "hotmail.com",
    "outlook.com"
};

foreach (string url in urls)
{
    //do whatever with the url
    Console.WriteLine(url);
}
```

Comment: Of course, `List<string>` is not an array - it's a list of strings.

Comment: @tomfanning It's a wrapper around an array.  You can think of it as pretty much just an array, but you're right, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all **links** you want into a Coolection of type: `IList<Link>` or into an `IEnumerable<Link>`

```
IList<Link> myCollection = new List<Link>();
```

After that, you'll go throuh items in the collection with an

```
foreach(var item in myCollection ) {
      //Here implement your logic with click
}
```

Comment: You can't `new` an `IList`.

Comment: @Servy - yes .. I miss that. Shouls be `IList<Link> myCollection = new List<Link>();` Thanks